# How to maintain linux/mac permissions on bind mount with docker for windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm currently developing a Drupal Application in my Mac. Drupal needs some permissions configuration in its subfolders (in linux) and all are already set up. I've got two containers: database (db) and apache-php (web). All my code is in git and I can get it with git clone or pull...

Just introducing the issue, do not worry about drupal or php, since this problem could happen with Python or any other scripting language.

I use bind mount with --volume directly from the code from git, this way (`docker-compose.yml`):

```
version: "2" 
services:   
  web:
    image: yoshz/apache-php:5.5
    links:
      - db:database
    volumes:
     - ./docker/phpconf/apache2:/etc/php5/apache2
     - ./www:/var/www
     - ./docker/sites-avaliable/:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
    ports:
      - "8600:80"   
  db:
    extends:
      file: docker-common-configs.yaml
      service: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

A colleague cloned my repository in Windows. Run `docker-compose up -d` and the application failed.

The problem is, as the volume resides in the **windows** host, permissions in ./www **are not set**.

I'd like to have the code accessible for the Windows Host Visual Code application, to change it fast, without deployment.

The solution of force permissions this way:

```
     - ./www:/var/www:rw
```

won't work, because each subdirectory has its own permissions.

Does anyone have an imaginative solution to face this problem?